# Extend Thread class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

With **Ruby 1.8.7** I am trying to extend Thread class here is snippet

```
class Foo < Thread
  attr_accessor :bar
end

t = Foo.new do 
  puts "Foo thread begins"
  self.bar = "Bar value" # also tried @bar
  sleep(2)
  puts "Foo thread ends"
end

puts "Value: #{t.bar}"
sleep(10)
puts "Value: #{t.bar}"
```

Output is

```
>Foo thread begins
>Value: 
>Foo thread ends
>Value:
```

Why am I not able to see `:bar` attribute for `Foo` class? Since this is probably not made to work this way, how do I pass value from my newly created `Thread` to `main` thread?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` in your thread refers to the main object, not `t`. Since the method `bar=` is not defined on the main object, it throws an error, which is not sent to the main thread.

There are several ways you can access the thread:

1) `Foo.new{p Foo.current}`

2) `Foo.new{|foo| p foo}`

3) `foo = Foo.new{p foo}`

Comment: how do I access it then, how can I set `bar` variable of my thread?

Comment: Thank you very much, this is probably not the best way to write thread safe programs but still learning. Thanks again.

Comment: I am pretty sure that `3)` will not work (at least it does not with 1.8.7) since foo is not evaluated while body of thread is executing. So you get `nil` there which would raise exception when trying to set property.

Comment: When you initiate a thread, it runs similtaneously with the main thread. At the moment it is created, the main thread can do the assignment. 3) is unstable, but may work. When it fails, that is when execution of `p foo` is earlier than the assigment of `foo = ...`. As long as you have a reasonable amount of code before calling `foo`, it should be okay. For example `foo = Foo.new{baz = :baz; p foo}` will be more stable. But it is not a safe way. You should not use it in practice.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to extend the Thread, you could try below instead.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar

  def run
    Thread.new do
      puts "Foo thread begins"
      self.bar = "Bar value" # also tried @bar
      sleep(2)
      puts "Foo thread ends"
    end
  end
end

t = Foo.new
t.run

puts "Value: #{t.bar}"
sleep(10)
puts "Value: #{t.bar}"
```

Comment: Thanks, great approach as well.